# Datastax / Cassandra tar ball installation & run as service

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I have downloaded & extracted the cassandra tar ball package. I'm able to run the process from the extracted location both in background & foreground mode. Could someone provide me instructions to run this as a service ?so that the service can start automatically when the server reboots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing piece here, is that you need a "casasandra" script in the `/etc/init.d/` directory.  While the `.deb` and `.rpm` packages take care of this for you, it is possible to write your own.  Essentially the init.d script needs to define variables to support your service, definition for the start/stop/restart functions, as well as some supporting methods.

Here's a [Git project which provides some detail](https://gist.github.com/naholyr/4275302) around how to do this, including a [new-service.sh](https://gist.github.com/naholyr/4275302#file-new-service-sh) script to do a lot of the heavy-lifting.  Note that you'll probably want to look over the finished product, and add some things specific to Cassandra (like disabling gossip and draining on a "stop").

Probably the easiest way to go about this, is to install with one of the above methods (using apt-get or yum) grab the `/etc/init.d/cassandra` file that it creates, and augment it for your deployment.